# PlayBook camera API (WebKit) throws an exception and does not open camera

Tags: javascript, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-webworks

So I am using the following code in an attempt to invoke the PlayBook camera, and have the user take a picture. The picture should then be returned to me as a file path String.

```
captureImage: function() {
    App.log("App.captureImage > Invoked");
    try {
        blackberry.media.camera.takePicture(App.takePictureComplete, App.cameraClosed, App.cameraError);
    } catch (err) {
        App.log("App.captureImage > Error Occured: " + err);
    }

    App.log("App.captureImage > Complete");
},

takePictureComplete: function(filePath) {
    App.log("App.takePictureComeplete > Image taken and file retrieved: " + filePath);
    App.origin.attr('src', filePath);
},
cameraClosed: function() {
    App.log("App.cameraClosed > Camera closed.");
},
cameraError: function(err) {
    App.log("App.cameraError > ERROR: " + err);
},
```

Here is a log of what happens. Notice that there is no logging from any of the callback functions, or in the catch block.

```
app.js:153 App.captureImage > Invoked
app.js:153 App.captureImage > Complete
index.html:187 TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'response.Response')
```

The line 187 that the exception is thrown on is part of the WebKit code and contains the following:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
   // continue if the process is completed
   if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
       // retrieve the response
       var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText, jsonReviver);
       responseCallback(response.Response); //LINE 187
   }
};
```

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this a problem with the API itself? As far as I can tell I have done everything the same way as the sample documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem，I guess we donot have the right feature or the  feature have wrong order，the camera work when I use the following feature （I find it in the webwork sample kitchensink）：
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<rim:permissions>
    <rim:permit>access_shared</rim:permit>
    <rim:permit>record_audio</rim:permit>
    <rim:permit>read_geolocation</rim:permit>
    <rim:permit>use_camera</rim:permit>
    <rim:permit>read_device_identifying_information</rim:permit>
</rim:permissions>

<!-- 
    Universal APIs: 
        The following features are available on both Smartphone and Tablet OS
-->
<feature id="blackberry.app" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.app.event" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.system" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.system.event" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.ui.dialog" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.utils" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>

<feature id="blackberry.media.camera" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.media.microphone" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.identity" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.io.file" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.io.dir" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>

<!-- 
    Smartphone APIs: 
        The following features are available ONLY on Smartphone
--> 
<feature id="blackberry.ui.menu" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.identity.phone" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke.AddressBookArguments" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke.BrowserArguments" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke.CalendarArguments" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke.CameraArguments" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke.JavaArguments" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke.MapsArguments" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke.MemoArguments" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke.MessageArguments" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke.PhoneArguments" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke.SearchArguments" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.invoke.TaskArguments" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.message" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.message.sms" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.pim.Address" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.pim.Attendee" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.pim.Appointment" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.pim.category" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.pim.Contact" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.pim.Memo" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.pim.Recurrence" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.pim.Reminder" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.pim.Task" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>

<feature id="blackberry.audio" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.audio.Player" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>

<feature id="blackberry.find" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.phone.Phone" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.phone.PhoneLogs" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>

<feature id="blackberry.push" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<feature id="blackberry.find" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>

<!-- 
    Tablet OS APIs: 
        The following features are available ONLY on Tablet OS
    ...
-->
<!--
COMMENT THE FOLLOWING WHEN BUILDING USING THE SMARTPHONE SDK.

<feature id="blackberry.payment" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
-->

<access subdomains="true" uri="*"/>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
good luck!